# What type of visualization is this and what are my options to produce something like it?

Tags: python, r, visualization

I am looking to reproduce the bottom part of the visualization below. What is this type of visualization called? What are my options to reproduce it? Preferably using Python or R, but I'm open to using other tools as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's similar to a [violin plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot), which shows the shape of the distribution of a variable. However here the X axis shows only categorical values, it's not clear if the shape is based on some underlying numerical variable (this is a requirement for a violin plot).

Violin plots can be made [in Python](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/violin-plot/) or [in R](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/violin.html).